# Page of "http://localhost/wordpress/" gives Error "404"?

Tags: wordpress, localhost

Page of "http://localhost/wordpress/" gives Error "404" for install of Wordpress.

I did following steps from https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/setting-up-xampp/?npl=b&utm_expid=3606929-89.qobzZlXrS1uV61bna13Vlw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F#ref site: "1.These lines of code define the login details for your database:

2.Replace“database_name_here” with the name of your database, which in my case is “WP” Replace “username_here” with “root” and leave “password_here” blank 3.Save the file and close it" But when i search "localhost/wp" in Browser gives Error 404.

Can you help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide details of what Server are you using. Check if you have your XAMPP/WAMP, LAMP is running. Add more details to your question.

Comment: I write detailes. I use from XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Page open with click on the "Admin" button according to the following foto:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting additional details as an answer

Comment: Well then there is something wrong with your xampp installation.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using xampp then url could be http://localhost/wp. Try this open xampp control panel then start the apache server and mysql, after doing this you can check if http://localhost gives any error, and there is wp or wordpress folder xampp htdocs. Then go to http://localhost/wp or http://localhost/wordpress.

Comment: This url too gives Error

Comment: Why could it be that url?

Comment: I thought so because some tuturials rename wordpress folder to wp like this one https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/setting-up-xampp/.